# Camel AggregationStrategy

Tags: apache-camel

I am using an AggregationStrategy to ensure that a particular header is populated in the oldExchange ...***all works fine...currently *** ...current code is:

---

```
.enrich("direct:step1-processing", new AggregationStrategy() {<br/>
   @Override<br/>
      public Exchange aggregate(final Exchange oldExchange, <br/>
                                final Exchange newExchange) {<br/>
       copyHeader(SomeBean.SpecificHeader_1, <br/>
                     newExchange, <br/>
                     oldExchange);<br/>
          return oldExchange;<br/>
      }<br/>
     })

.enrich("direct:step2-processing", new AggregationStrategy() {<br/>
    @Override<br/>
      public Exchange aggregate(final Exchange oldExchange, <br/>
                                final Exchange newExchange) {<br/>
       copyHeader(SomeBean.SpecificHeader_2, <br/>
                     newExchange, <br/>
                     oldExchange);<br/>
          return oldExchange;<br/>
      }<br/>
     })

void copyHeader(final String headerName, <br/>
                final Exchange newExchange, <br/>
                final Exchange oldExchange) {<br/>
        oldExchange.getIn().setHeader(
             headerName, <br/>
             newExchange.getIn().getHeader(headerName));<br/>
}
```

---

My goal is to move the AggregationStrategy code to it's own class rather than having the code inline. That, in and of itself is not an issue, the question is how to pass in that parameter ( *SomeBean.SpecificHeader_1 or SomeBean.SpecificHeader_2* ) which is specifying which header value is to copied from the old exchange to the new exchange.

As far as I can tell, the **public Exchange aggregate(** method does not allow a parameter other than old & new exchange to be passed in.

Comment: Can you drop all these `<br/>` ? The code is hard to read and test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1: Define your own strategy**

You could have a separate instance of `AggregationStrategy` for each specific header:

```
public class MyAggregationStrategy implements AggregationStrategy {

    private String headerName;

    public MyAggregationStrategy(String headerName) {
        this.headerName = headerName;
    }

    @Override
    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
        copyHeader(newExchange, oldExchange);
        return oldExchange;
    }

    void copyHeader(final Exchange newExchange,
                    final Exchange oldExchange) {
        oldExchange.getIn().setHeader(
                headerName,
                newExchange.getIn().getHeader(headerName));
    }

}
```

Then use these strategies like this:

```
.enrich("direct:step1-processing", new MyAggregationStrategy(SomeBean.SpecificHeader_1))
.enrich("direct:step2-processing", new MyAggregationStrategy(SomeBean.SpecificHeader_2))
```

**Solution 2: Use lambda's**

With your original `copyHeaders()` method slightly adapted:

```
Exchange copyHeader(final String headerName,
                final Exchange newExchange,
                final Exchange oldExchange) {
    oldExchange.getIn().setHeader(
            headerName,
            newExchange.getIn().getHeader(headerName));
    return oldExchange;
}
```

Then defined the needed strategies:

```
AggregationStrategy header1Strategy = (oldExchange, newExchange) -> copyHeader("my-header-1", oldExchange, newExchange);
AggregationStrategy header2Strategy = (oldExchange, newExchange) -> copyHeader("my-header-2", oldExchange, newExchange);
```

Finally use them:

```
.enrich("direct:step1-processing", header1Strategy)
.enrich("direct:step2-processing", header2Strategy);
```

Comment: Yes ...I considered that and that is indeed a workable option ...I was hoping for something a little more elegant so I did not have to have multiple Aggregation Strategy classes

Comment: You could set the header in the route before calling `enrich` via `setHeader` and then you can get the header from the exchange via `exchange.getIn().getHeader("Headername")`.

Comment: Actually ...looking at your example, it would appear that example would work ...not sure if / why I would need more than that one class ...I would simply call this class something like following <br/>.enrich("direct:step2-processing", new MyAggregationStrategy(SomeBean.SpecificHeader_2))<br/> ...or am i missing something ?

Comment: @RM Yes. You don't need more than on class. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks ! kind of obvious once you provided the example :=)